# Resolve Module Path Within Another Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, scope, autoload

I have classes namespaced into modules at `app/objects/v4/mobile/checkin.rb`

I am calling them inside another module namespaced at `controllers/v4/mobile/checkin.rb`

I am referencing the first module as `V4::Mobile::Checkin` but I am doing it inside the second module so the path is being resolved as `V4::Mobile::Checkin::V4::Mobile::Checkin`

Is there anyway to resolve the path from `app/` as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prefix your module name with '::', then it will be resolved from the top level namespace

```
::V4::Mobile::Checkin
```